# How to Update a Row with an existing Row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a product table. I have some empty rows. I want to fill these rows with an existing row. For example, if I have

```
Product
-----------------------------------
ID   Name  Desc  ---------------
1     A     A1   ---------------
2     B     B1   ---------------
3     C     C1   ---------------
```

I want to copy all the items of ID=1 into ID = 3 row.

Tried this but getting error, Ambigious

```
UPDATE [Products]
SET DP.[Name] = SP.Name 
    ,DP.[Desc] = SP.DESC                          
FROM    [Products] DP
       INNER JOIN [Products] SP ON SP.ID = 3
WHERE DP.ID = 1
```

Comment: [What have **you** tried??](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Comment: @Thanks Deepak. I have seearched but havent found any

Comment: please post the complete error. it might contain hints about what the problem was with the query

Comment: The [`MERGE` statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) in SQL Server 2008 and later is great for bulk updates.

Comment: @pete can you give an example how to do the above with Merge statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use alias - either DP or SP in UPDATE and not Products itself because it's ambiguous between the two.

```
UPDATE DP
SET DP.[Name] = SP.Name 
    ,DP.[Desc] = SP.[DESC]                          
FROM    [Products] DP
INNER JOIN [Products] SP ON SP.ID = 3
WHERE DP.ID = 1
```